# Improve the performance of Reactjs for rendering large amount of components

Tags: reactjs, performance, rendering, react-virtualized

I am developing a gallery and I have a performance problem when I exceed 200 components.
Currently in my gallery I can filter images and sort them according to certain attributes.
I tried to use the "Lazy Load" to improve the performance but it brings me other problems that I did not have before. Moreover it does not solve the problem if I still display all my elements.
I would like to try a thing a bit like "react-virtualized" which updates the DOM permanently but I do not really know how to do it and I have the impression that "react-virtualized" was not thought for operate with entire components.

My Gallery component looks like that:

```
const Gallery = memo(props => {
  const { imgs } = props;
  const { onClickHere } = props;
  return (
    <div className="cards-container">
      {imgs.map((img, index) => (
        <GalleryImage
          img={img}
          index={index}
          onClickHere={onClickHere}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
});
```

My Image component looks like that:

```
const Image = props => {
  const { img } = props;
  const { index } = props;
  const { onClickHere } = props;
  const { alt } = props;

  return (
    <div className="cards-child">
      <div className="gallery-card">
        <img className="gallery-thumbnail" src={img.uri} alt={alt} />
        <div className="card-info">
          <span className="card-info_text">
            <span className="badge badge-secondary">
              {img.attr.join(", )} 
            </span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <span className="card-icon-open fa fa-expand" onClick={e => {onClickHere(e, img, index);}} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

These components display a clickable image list that is all the same size.
Do you know if I can actually use react-virtualized and did it badly (if that's the case can you help me to see more clearly) or do you know a way to improve these performances ?

Answer (score 0):

On one hand we have the render cycle from the Virtual DOM. In this case React will render every component when its props change or when its parent renders.

To improve performance here you could memoize the component so that it will only render if its props change, and not when the parent changes. So in your case, you probably want to [memoize](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) `Image` rather than `Gallery`. Note that `Gallery` is receiving `onClickHere` and passing it to `Image`. Make sure the callback is wrapped in a `useCallback` so a new reference is not created on every render (which `memo` would recognize as a new parameter and render the component).

On the other hand we have the actual DOM rendering. In this case React will only render anything if there is a change, and only change the necessary HTML.

Virtualization plugins help to avoid rendering all the HTML, and only redering the necessary. This is helpful so the browser has the minimum necessary HTML, because if the amount of nodes is large it might be laggy. Before implementing these try to reduce the amount of divs inside `Image` to a minimum.

---

Only apply performance improvements when necessary and test to see if you are getting benefits from them or not. In your case the main issue might be displaying too many HTML elements. Also it seems like your map function is missing a `key`.